# Why can't I create a vendor bill in SuiteScript?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am unable to save a vendor bill, as it will come up with an error that inventory details are required when I do not enter them. However, when I attempt to enter any values for the inventory-related fields, it will come up with an error of "You cannot create an inventory detail for this item.". The available item fields are as follows (copied from debugger):

```
amount = {string}  
amounthasbeenset = {string} 
billreceipts = {string}  
billvariancestatus = {string}  
billvariancestatusallbook = {string}  
binitem = {string}  
class = {string}  
customer = {string}  
ddistrib = {string}  
department = {string}  
description = {string}  
fulfillable = {string}  
fulfillmentstatus = {string}  
generateaccruals = {string}  
groupsetup = {string}  
hasimmutableamortization = {string}  
id = {string}  
inboundshipmentitem = {string}  
includegroupwrapper = {string}  
ingroup = {string}  
initoqpbucket = {string}  
initquantity = {string}  
inventorydetailavail = {string}  
inventorydetailreq = {string}  
isbillable = {string}  
islinefulfilled = {string}  
islinkedtodropshippoline = {string}  
isnoninventory = {string}  
isnumbered = {string}  
isserial = {string}  
item = {string}  
itemhandlingcost = {string}  
itemresidamt = {string}  
itemresidamtispct = {string}  
itemshippingcost = {string}  
itemsubtype = {string}  
itemtype = {string}  
landedcostcategory = {string}  
landedcostset = {string}  
linenumber = {string}  
location = {string}  
locationusebins = {string}  
locationusesbins = {string}  
mandatorylocation = {string}
marginal = {string}  
matrixtype = {string}  
olditemid = {string}  
options = {string}  
oqpbucket = {string}  
orderdoc = {string}  
orderline = {string}  
origlocation = {string}  
origrate = {string}  
printitems = {string}  
quantity = {string}  
rate = {string}  
rateschedule = {string}  
scheduletype = {string}  
tracklandedcost = {string}  
vendorname = {string}  
weightinlb = {string}
```

I am setting the following inventory detail values (in addition to item, quantity, and location). There is no inventoryassignment sublist.

```
inventorydetailavail = F
inventorydetailreq = F
binitem = F
isserial = F
isnumbered = F
locationusesbins = F
locationusebins = F
itemtype = NonInvtPart
isnoninventory = T
```

Here is an example of the code I am using:

```
define(['N/record','N/redirect','N/search'],
function(record, redirect, search) {

/**
 * Definition of the Suitelet script trigger point.
 *
 * @param {Object} context
 * @param {ServerRequest} context.request - Encapsulation of the incoming request
 * @param {ServerResponse} context.response - Encapsulation of the Suitelet response
 * @Since 2015.2
 */
function onRequest(context) {

    var request = context.request;
    var response = context.response;

    var id = context.request.parameters.custom_id;
    if (!id) {
        context.response.write('The parameter "custom_id" is required');
        return;
    }
    else {
        alert('ID is ' + id);
    }

    var loadedRecord = record.load({
        type: record.Type.INBOUND_SHIPMENT,
        id: id
    });

    alert('Generating vendor bill');

    var shipmentBaseCurrency = loadedRecord.getValue('shipmentbasecurrency');

    var vendorBill = record.create({
        type: record.Type.VENDOR_BILL,
        isDynamic: true
    });

    vendorBill.setValue('currency', shipmentBaseCurrency);

    var receivingLocation = '';

    var lines = loadedRecord.getLineCount({sublistId: 'items'});
    log.debug("tran. lines: " + lines);

    var total;

    for (var i = 0; i < lines; i++) {

        var quantity = (parseFloat(loadedRecord.getSublistValue({
            sublistId: "items",
            fieldId: "quantityreceived",
            line: i
        })) || 0);

        var purchaseOrder = loadedRecord.getSublistValue({
            sublistId: "items",
            fieldId: "purchaseorder",
            line: i
        });

        var item = loadedRecord.getSublistValue({
            sublistId: "items",
            fieldId: "itemid",
            line: i
        });

        var description = loadedRecord.getSublistValue({
            sublistId: "items",
            fieldId: "shipmentitemdescription",
            line: i
        });

        var recLoc = loadedRecord.getSublistValue({
            sublistId: "items",
            fieldId: "receivinglocation",
            line: i
        });

        receivingLocation = recLoc;

        var totalUnitCost = loadedRecord.getSublistValue({
            sublistId: "items",
            fieldId: "totalunitcost",
            line: i
        });

        var amount = loadedRecord.getSublistValue({
            sublistId: "items",
            fieldId: "shipmentitemamount",
            line: i
        });

        log.debug("item quantity: " + quantity);

        vendorBill = addVendorBillLine(vendorBill, item, quantity, receivingLocation);

    } // for (var i = 0; i < lines; i++)

    var vbPostPeriodValStr = String(getPostingPeriod());
    try {
        vendorBill.setText('postingperiod', vbPostPeriodValStr);
    }
    catch(e) {
        log.error('Issue setting posting period for vendor bill', e.message);
    }

    vendorBill.setValue('location', receivingLocation);

    try {
        var vendorBillId = vendorBill.save(); 
        log.debug('*******Vendor Bill Saved*******', 'Vendor bill successfully saved: ' + vendorBillId);
        redirect.toRecord({
            type: record.Type.VENDOR_BILL, 
            id: vendorBillId 
        });
    }
    catch(e) {
        log.debug('Error saving vendor bill', e.message);
        context.response.write('Error: ' + e.message);
    }
}

function addVendorBillLine(vendorBill, item, quantity, location) {
    try {
        var lineNum = vendorBill.selectNewLine({
            sublistId: 'item'
        });

        vendorBill.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: "item",
            fieldId: "item",
            value: item
        });

        vendorBill.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: "item",
            fieldId: "quantity",
            value: quantity
        });

        vendorBill.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: "item",
            fieldId: "location",
            value: location
        });

        vendorBill.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: "item",
            fieldId: "itemtype",
            value: 'NonInvtPart'
        });

        vendorBill.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: "item",
            fieldId: "isnoninventory",
            value: 'T'
        });

        vendorBill.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: "item",
            fieldId: "inventorydetailreq",
            value: 'F'
        });
        vendorBill.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: "item",
            fieldId: "inventorydetailavail",
            value: 'F'
        });
        vendorBill.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: "item",
            fieldId: "binitem",
            value: 'F'
        });
        vendorBill.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: "item",
            fieldId: "locationusebins",
            value: 'F'
        });

        vendorBill.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: "item",
            fieldId: "vendorname",
            value: 'Test Vendor'
        });

        vendorBill.commitLine({sublistId:"item"});

        log.debug('Committing vendor bill expense line addition','Name: ' + item + ", Quantity: " + quantity);
    }
    catch(e){
        log.debug('Issue committing vendor bill item line addition', e.message);
    }

    return vendorBill;
}

function getPostingPeriod() {
    var monthAbbr = [
        "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
        "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
    ];

    var d = new Date();
    return monthAbbr[d.getMonth()] + ' ' + d.getFullYear();
}

return {
    onRequest: onRequest
};

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too faced alot of problems while creating **itemfulfillment** from SuiteScript. I haven't tried creating vendorbill yet, but the same rules should apply to it since you need to set **inventorydetails**. While creating ItemFulfillments here is what I found

1. Apparently `hasSublistSubrecord/hasSubrecord` does not always returns a valid value, i.e it returns true even if a sublist item does not have subrecord for inventoryDetails(no serial, lot or bin) so you need to search and verify if your current item requires inventory details i.e has serial, lot or bin enabled.
2. NetSuite did not allow using `dynamicMode = true` while creating **inventorydetails** on records, so had to use **nonDynamic** mode only while creating records with inventoryDetails.
3. `getSubRecord\getSublistSubrecord` does not throws an error if an item does not have serial, lot or bin enabled, which means using `getSubRecord\getSublistSubrecord` on line item which does not have serial, lot or bin number will return a subrecord but if you set **inventorydetails** in it, NetSuite will throw an error **You cannot create an inventory detail for this item**.